# How to initialize value in data class constructor kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-room, data-class

I want to initialize the value of image when data is fetched from server I tried this but value isn't updating.

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories")
data class Category(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val name: String,
    var image: String,
){
   init{
     image = "someUrl" + image
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to have `image` save the full path of some URL.

An idea to achieve this is to have a backing field into Category class like the following

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "categories")
data class Category(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val name: String,
    var image: String,
){
   val imageUrl: String
       get() = "some Url" + image
}
```

Then when you want to load the image you could have

```kotlin
val item:Category
imgViwew.load(item.imageUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with the help of [JPA lifecycle events](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events), like this:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "categories")
data class Category(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val name: String,
    var image: String,
){

   @PostLoad // <---
   fun postLoad() {
     image = "someUrl" + image
   } 
}
```